# Running command from SH

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sh

I'm trying to write a script that checks if something is running and start it if it isn't.

```
trap "kill 0" SIGINT

while :
do
    live-stream-radio --start myStream
done
```

The output I get though is:

```
start_stream.sh: 8: start_stream.sh: live-stream-radio: not found
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick!

Comment: Great, I'll convert it to an answer so you can mark it resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `not found` error makes it look as if `live-stream-radio` might not be on your path.

Rather than figuring out the details of your run environment, I suggest you 
simply specify the full path of that tool explicitly. If you're able to run the command from an interactive shell, then you can find out where it's located with the following:

```
which live-stream-radio
```

If the result is, say, `/usr/local/bin/live-stream-radio`, you'd simply add that to your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

trap "kill 0" SIGINT

while :; do
  /usr/local/bin/live-stream-radio --start myStream
done
```